# Do the games bought in one country will work on PS4 which is bought in another country?

Tags: ps4

I have bought couple of PS4 games from Switzerland and I am still is in Switzerland. Will the games work on PS4 which is bought in India?

If not, is there an alternative approach to play these games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you are good with playing your owned games anywhere in the world (until specific game publisher decides to mess with their games). From [this playstation.com blog](https://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/10/30/ps4-the-ultimate-faq-north-america/)

> **Do PS4 games have regional locks?**
>
> In general, neither digital nor disc-based games will be region locked, but PlayStation recommends that all users purchase games at the region of their residence to guarantee the best overall experience and customer service. In certain instances, a software publisher may choose to region lock a game title for specific reasons, but Sony Computer Entertainment expects these instances to be uncommon.

However, some multiplayer games may have region based matchmaking, this could make it impossible to play with your friends from other regions.

Answer (score -2):

Yes all games work there shouldnt be any reason why it doest work